# Passing a variable to a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know this has been asked before but I think I'm doing everything right and it still wont work.

I have a simple user table one to many with a relationship table. I just want to show the number of people following a selected user in a partial.
It works fine in the non partial view but I keep getting the error:

```
 undefined method `name'
```

when I make the normal view into a partial and it highlights the focus of the error as being

```
def gravatar_for(user, size = 30, title = user.name)
```

which is fromm a helper method I use

the partial is here (called `users/_show_follow` ):

```
<% provide(:title, @title) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section class="user_info">
      <%= gravatar_for user %>
      <h1><%= user.name %></h1>
      <span><%= link_to "view my profile", user %></span>
    </section>

    <section class="stats">
      <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
      <% if users.any? %>
        <div class="user_avatars">
          <% for user in users %>  
            <%= link_to gravatar_for(user, size: 30), user %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </section>


  </aside>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <h3><%= @title %></h3>
    <% if users.any? %>
      <ul class="users follow">
        <%= render users %>
      </ul>
      <%= will_paginate %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The originating page for the partial:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="col-md-8">
                <div id="chart"><%= javascript_include_tag('graph') %></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
                <p>
                <h2>Node Score</h2>
                <div id="FBDiv"></div>
                <div id="chart_1"></div>
                <h2>Node Profile</h2>
                <div id="NodeProfile"></div>
                <h2>My inner circle</h2>
                <h2>Wants to connect</h2>
                <h2>My profile</h2>
                <%= current_user.about %>
                      <section class="stats">
                <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
                <%= render :partial => "show_follow", :locals => {:user => @user, :users => @users} %>
      </section>
      </section>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the controller

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController


    def index
         @users = User.including_relationships
         respond_to do |format|
         format.html # index.html.erb
         format.json {  render json: @users } 
         end
    end

     def show
      @user = User.find_by name: params[:name]
        respond_to do |format|
          # Here we need to remove the layout because the request
          # is done via ajax and the layout is already loaded.
          format.json {  render json: @user.to_json } 
        end
     end

     def following
          @title = "Following"
          @user = User.find(params[:id])
          @users = @user.followed_users.paginate(page: params[:page])
          render 'show_follow'
      end

      def followers
          @title = "Followers"
          @user = User.find(params[:id])
          @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
          render 'show_follow'
      end
    end

the helper

 module ApplicationHelper
   def page_header(text)
    content_for(:page_header) { text.to_s }
  end

  def gravatar_for(user, title = user.name, size = 30)
    image_tag gravatar_image_url(user.email, size: size), title: title, class: 'img-rounded'
  end
 end
```

Is the problem how I pass the variable into the helper method from the partial?

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out the error is on your helper arguments: `def gravatar_for(user, size = 30, title = user.name)`. `user` is not an object, it'simply the name of the argument, so `user.name` won't work.

Try setting a default title (1) or passing the title when you call the method (2):

1. `def gravatar_for(user, size = 30, title = 'Default name')`
2. `<%= gravatar_for user, 20, user.name %>`. To avoid passing the size each time you can reorder the arguments: `def gravatar_for(user, title = user.name, size = 30)` or use [keyword arguments](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments).

Comment: Choice 2 trips up on the user.email and gives me undefined method `email'. How come the non partial version works?

Comment: I don't see where are you calling `user.email`.

Comment: Im tryin to use the user object for a bunch of different queries so I am trying to see if I can get other values from the database- the answer tripped up on trying to ger user.email. I've added it to the code

Comment: and the user.email is in the helper method- this is why Im trying to find out how to pass a partial variable to a helper